# How to show a button after a specific time period?

Tags: android, service

I am developing an android app in which when user click  on the **in** button, **out** button should be hidden for 8 hours or hours given by the user and after 8 hours **out** button should be visible and if the user forgot to click on the **out** button it should automatically mark him out.

I searched I come to know about android services but I didn't understand how to achieve this by using service.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can do it easily if you want to keep your app in `foreground` but if you want to keep it in background you have to create an background service for your app to run continously. And for your timespam you can use `AlarmManager` with 8hrs time(or any custom user time - by variable)

Comment: I want to keep it in the background can you explain little briefly as I am new in android.

Comment: just store the current time into the local storage or shared data and when user come to this activity compare the store time with current time its a good way even you killed the app and restart the phone its working

Answer (score 0):

Use alaram manager & pending intent with broadcast reciver like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AlarmBroadCast.class);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2); //Set your time here
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

//Broadcast reciver
public class AlarmBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Implement your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: in calendar. add I have to give time in milliseconds and where I place of 2 ??? sorry but I am new so does not have that much knowledge...

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.MILLI_SECONDS, YOUR_VALUE_PASS_HERE);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad and unclear regarding your exact requirements. However, I can list a few points to help you get a logic.

**Scenarios and Steps:**

1. Initially, there are 2 buttons on the activity, **In** and **Out**.
2. Once the user clicks on the `In` button, simply hide the `Out` button, and save a `timestamp` in your `SharedPreferences` file.
3. With this, if the activity is still being displayed, the `Out` button will be hidden.
4. Create an `AlarmManager` as answered by **Bhaskar Pasupula**, but for `8 Hours ahead of the currentTime`.
5. When your class receives the `BroadcastReceiver`, cross-check the difference between `currentTimeStamp` (fetched inside the receiver) and the `timestamp` saved in your `SharedPreferences`. If the difference is greater than equal to 8 hours, you can delete the key/value from the file.
6. Now, inside your activity, under `onCreate` method, fetch the value for the same key as used for saving the check-in timestamp. If the key is **present**, it means the user **hasn't pressed the `out` button yet.** The reason is simply that 8 hours haven't passed yet. Hence, hide the button before the activity is displayed to the user.
7. If the key is **not present**, it means, `8 hours has passed` and hence, show the button.